# How to increase the scrollback history of the Python console/terminal within Blender?

Tags: interface, command-line

How can I increase the size of the command history in the Python console?
The console options don't provide any option for doing this.

Like Maya's unlimited output section in the script editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by going to *User Preferences > System* and changing the value in *Console Scrollback* under the *General* category. It's set to `256` by default.

Comment: Anyway of setting it to unlimited. Plus, since it doesn't provide text area for increase the value to something extreme high, therefore unlimited, is there a way to programmatically change that value?

Comment: @BleedingFingers Some fields in Blender can be overwritten with custom values but others are built in such as this. One would also think that the limit (32768) is pretty much 'umlimited' in terms of history.

Comment: Coming from Maya I don't find that number quite high. Although it was quite easy to set it to that value.

Comment: What do you need such a large history for? If you really need it, increase the maximum value here: `blender\source\blender\makesrna\intern\rna_userdef.c` and compile

Comment: @CoDEmanX (You forgot the the `@` ping ;)). 1). The software or its plugin starts malfunctioning, having the entire history would be quite helpful for inspection by the dev team 2). Scene file (GBs in size) gets corrupt, reconstruct as much as possible by evaling its content in pieces and have the peace of mind that nothing is lost is eaten up. 3). testing an intersection finding program on a large scene overnight, coming back to see if anything went wrong then what was the sequence of things and the traces. 4). Run a large loop on 4M edges and use the result for whatever reason.

Comment: @BleedingFingers: 1.) I doubt devs will be amused by giant logs 2.) Serialization of actions is not possible, but if all you do is to run Py code line by line, why don't you replace the execute operator shortcut to intercept it, log to an external file and call execute()?